# Power BI - How to display multiple measures across rows & columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In my Power BI report I have some measures which calculate various KPIs. Some but not all of these KPIs have a additional measure calculating their growth vs a forecast.

I want to display all of my measures in this format:

| Performance | Performance vs forecast |
| --- | --- |
| KPI_1 | KPI_1_vs_forecast |
| KPI_2 |  |
| KPI_3 | KPI_3_vs_forecast |

To be clear, each of the five values beginning with 'KPI_' is a separate measure. The column headers don't come from any table or measure; they're just what I'd like displayed on the report.

A transposed version of this result where the column headers are row headers instead would also be fine.

I can set up the 'Performance' column using a multi row card, but if I set up a corresponding multi row card for 'Performance vs forecast' then the measures become misaligned:

| Performance | Performance vs forecast |
| --- | --- |
| KPI_1 | KPI_1_vs_forecast |
| KPI_2 | KPI_3_vs_forecast |
| KPI_3 |  |

I can have each measure be displayed by a separate card and arrange the cards as I wish, but I feel there has to be a more elegant solution. I've tried using a table visual, but I could only get it to display all of the measures on a single row.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve the desired result please?

Comment: Do  you have a sample .pbix?

Comment: @DavideBacci unfortunately the raw data in the .pbix file is confidential so I cannot share it. I could create a mock up with some dummy data, but is there a means of sharing this via stack overflow? I'm not aware of a way to attach files to my question.

Comment: Just upload a mockup to an external site and post a link here.